# Optimizing multiple if-else from static class with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a static class:

```
public static class ConfigurationDetails
{
    public static string SharepointServer { get; set; }
    public static string Username { get; set; }
    public static string Password { get; set; }
    public static string SharepointDomain { get; set; }
    public static string ServiceLibrary { get; set; }
    public static string SqlServer { get; set; }
    public static string SQLUsername { get; set; }
    public static string SQLPassword { get; set; }
    public static string SQLDomain { get; set; }
}
```

which needs to be updated from the values of a dictionary.

Using if the code is below:

```
var configValues = ReadConfiguration();

if (configValues.ContainsKey("SharepointServer"))
{
    ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = configValues["SharepointServer"];

}
if (configValues.ContainsKey("ServiceLibrary"))
{
    ConfigurationDetails.ServiceLibrary = configValues["ServiceLibrary"];

}
if (configValues.ContainsKey("Username"))
{
    ConfigurationDetails.Username = configValues["Username"];

}
if (configValues.ContainsKey("Password"))
{
    ConfigurationDetails.Password= configValues["Password"];

}
```

Now this will do the job, but there would be a lot of `if`s. I've tried with LINQ, but this is the closest I've gotten:

```
configValues.Where(kv => kv.Key == "SharepointServer").ToList().ForEach(kv => ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = kv.Value);
```

and it's not doing any good. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: As a side-note: I wouldn't make configuration a static class

Comment: How much control do you have over the ReadConfiguration method?  Could it be refactored to return a ConfigurationDetails instance rather than a dictionary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution would be to encapsulate the logic into a method. A problem with that is that there is no simple way to pass a property to the method.

If the case where the key is not in the dictionary means that the value is `null`, then you could write an extension method for `IDictionary` that returns the value, if it's present, or `null`:

```
public static string GetValueOrDefault(this IDictionary<string, string> dict, string key)
{
    string result;
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out result);
    return result;
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = configValues.GetValueOrDefault("SharepointServer");
```

Another option (assuming the names of properties and keys always match) would be to use reflection to set all the properties at the same time. Something like:

```
var properties = typeof(ConfigurationDetails).Getproperties();
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    string value;
    if (configValues.TryGetValue(property.Name, out value))
    {
        property.SetValue(null, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off: 
I think, LINQ is of little help.

1. You could do yourself a favour and change your configuration to a Dictionary and the problem would not occur.
2. You could do it with the ternary operator:

   ```
   ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer=(configValues.ContainsKey("SharepointServer"))?configValues["SharepointServer"]:default;
   ```

   To make things easier, you could wrap it up into a method like svick's solution
3. You could do it like svick
4. You could do it automagically, if you drop the idea of a static class, which is by the way nasty, and deal with a configuration object. then, you could leverage *reflection* to set the according fields, depending on the keys in your dictionary.

Comment: Oooh automagic reflection... I like :) and +1 for static class being nasty!

Answer (score 3):

I would carefully think about the class design.

Do you really want your configuration values to be writable from outside the ConfigurationDetails class?

Is ReadConfiguration a really expensive method? If not, why should you read the configuration once instead of reading it every time when user requests it? [In the current design, how would user force a refresh of configuration?]

Do you really want to return NULL for setting value when it's not configured? I prefer to throw a helpful exception which can help me troubleshoot the problem just in case I forgot to specify a key or mistyped it.

I can not answer the above questions for you but this is what you should think about.

Assuming that ReadConfiguration method is cheap, here's how I would write the ConfigurationDetails class.

```
public static class ConfigurationDetails
{
    public static string SharepointServer {  get { return GetConfigValue('SharepointServer'; }

    public static string Username {  get { return GetConfigValue("Username"); }

    public static string Password {  get { return GetConfigValue("Password"); }

    /* Fill in the rest */

    private static string GetConfigValue(string key)
    {
        var configValues = ReadConfiguration();

        if(! configValues.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Could not find configuration for key " + key);

        return configValues[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if the configuration changes infrequently (or not at all), you could change ConfigurationDetails to be an instance class and use a Lazy<T> field for the configuration dictionary.  In the case where there are infrequent changes, you can have a method to reset (i.e., re-assign) the field.

Answer (score 2):

I know it would not be worth answering this question, but I would like to suggest that using a dictionary and expecting optimization would not be a good idea.

I have tried to refactor my conditions from `if`/`else` or `switch` to dictionary, and you won't believe that it has cost me more resources than a simple `if`/`else`.

So you could try to resolve this issue by using Strategy Patterns.  That can help you out for such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Compressed code could look like:

```
string dictValue;
ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = 
    configValues.TryGetValue("SharepointServer", out dictValue) 
    ? dictValue : null;
```

TryGetValue also sets dictValue to null if it fails, thus no init required on declaration.

Anyway, I would not like a static class, but pass the dictionary to a constructor or Configure(IDictionary ...) method, and also validate the input before taking it into the config.